# Typescript Error - Object doesn't support property or method tooltip

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, typescript, tooltip, frontend, angular2-template

I am new to Angular 2 framework. I am trying to add a tooltip to a button, but it doesn't seems to work. I am using Angular 2 with typescript framework with Bootstrap.

This is the button I want to add Tooltip:

```
<button class="btn btn-default" id="myButton" [title]=myTip data-toggle="tooltip">My Button</button>
```

myTip is defined in .ts file contructor:

```
this.myTip: string;
this.myTip = "This is a tip";
```

Also in .ts file, I am using the following way to initialize tooltip, visual studio compiler didn't throw error.

```
import { Component, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
import * as $ from 'jquery';
export class Utterance implements AfterViewInit{
   ngAfterViewInit() {
       $('myButton').tooltip();
   }
}
```

However, after loading the page. Browser is giving me the error:

```
TypeError: Object doesn't support property or method 'tooltip'
```

Could you please help take a look why this is having error and how should I fix it, thanks!

Comment: Along with jQuery you also need to import the JavaScript for Botstrap components. So, either import `tooltip.js` individually if you like or simply import `bootstrap.min.js` to import everything. Refer: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/javascript/#tooltips

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Let me take a look.